# Mat Form field does not load classes on pressing back button after routerLink Navigation

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, mat-form-field

Suppose I have a page A with Mat form field and I navigate to page B via routerlink and I press back button on the browser top/mobile, Some of Css and classes of mat form field are not loaded(like .mat-primary .mat-form-field-type-mat-input .mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-can-float .mat-form-field-has-label .mat-form-field-hide-placeholder) How can it be fixed and possible Expaination.
(This error is not produced when the page reloads(Like with href).

Image of component A when loaded.
[image]

Image of Component A when its loaded after routerLink and Back button
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally fix after solving the console error : A MatDatepicker can only be associated with a single input.